# Grails - How to create a closure from String data

Tags: grails

I want to build a closure from String data. So that, if my String is `"a.b.c.d"`, then my closure should be `a{b{c{sort(d, order)}}}`. If my String is `"x.y"`, then my closure should be `x{sort(y, order)}`

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17127415/2051952) generic approach help in any ways?

Comment: That seems like its exactly what OP wants