# Dynamically constructing closures from a map?

Tags: soap, groovy, closures

I'm trying to make a general method for sending SOAP requests and getting responses. I'm programming using Groovy and I'm using the [wslite](https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite) library to help me out with SOAP. Here's a sample snippet for making a SOAP request and getting a response:

```
@Grab('com.github.groovy-wslite:groovy-wslite:1.1.2')
import wslite.soap.*

SOAPClient client = new SOAPClient('http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx')
def response = client.send(SOAPAction: 'http://tempuri.org/Add') {
     body {
          Add(xmlns: 'http://tempuri.org/') {
               intA(x)
               intB(y)
          }
     }
}
```

By general, I meant being able to dynamically create a SOAP request (given certain information such as the service/method name, the parameters contained in the method, etc.) and obtain the SOAP response. I'm thinking something like this:

```
@Grab('com.github.groovy-wslite:groovy-wslite:1.1.2')
import wslite.soap.*

def getResponse(String clientURL, String action, String service, String serviceNamespace, Map parameters, ...) {
     SOAPClient client = new SOAPClient(clientURL)
     def response = client.send(SOAPAction: action) {
          body {
               "$service"(xmlns: serviceNameSpace) {
               ...
               }
          }
     }
}
```

My problem lies in constructing the closure for the request body. Like, in example, if my method received a `service` `Add`, a `serviceNamespace` `http://tempuri.org/`, and a `parameter` map like so: `[intA: x, intB: y]`... how do I merge all of these so that I can construct this kind of closure:

```
Add(xmlns: 'http://tempuri.org/') {
     intA(x)
     intB(y)
}
```

I'm pretty much a newbie to Groovy, so don't be too harsh. If there's a better way to implement this concept of a general method, I would gladly like to hear it. The concept is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120788/create-dynamically-closures-in-groovy-from-a-string-object). But I'd rather play with `Map` than a `String`. I'm not using Grails, really. Just plain Groovy.

Comment: would `[intA: x, intB: y].each{fn,arg -> delegate."$fn"(arg) }` do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, cfrick is correct:

```
[intA: x, intB: y].each{fn,arg -> delegate."$fn"(arg) }
```

## How does it work?

An easy way to see how this works is to simulate it with a fake client class:

```
groovy.util.NodeBuilder

class Client {
    def send(String action, Closure closure) {
        closure.delegate = new NodeBuilder()

        closure()
    }
}

def client = new Client()

def response = client.send('http://tempuri.org/Add') {
    body {
        Add(xmlns: 'http://tempuri.org/') {
               intA(1)
               intB(2)
          }
    }   
}

assert response.Add[0].@xmlns == 'http://tempuri.org/'
assert response.Add.intA.text() == '1'
assert response.Add.intB.text() == '2'
```

In the example above, the `response` object is created by Groovy's [NodeBuilder](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/NodeBuilder.html). It's just a quick way to prototype something that processes the closure passed to `Client.send()`.

With this testable code I'll try what cfrick suggested and validate that it works:

```
def doIt(String action, String service, String serviceNamespace, Map params) {
    def client = new Client()

    client.send(action) {
        body {
            "$service"(xmlns: serviceNamespace) {
                    params.each { method, argument ->
                        delegate."$method"(argument)
                    }
              }
        }   
    }
}

response = doIt('http://tempuri.org/Add', 'Add', 'http://tempuri.org/', [intA: 1, intB: 2])

assert response.Add[0].@xmlns == 'http://tempuri.org/'
assert response.Add.intA.text() == '1'
assert response.Add.intB.text() == '2'
```

## Request Body

In addition, you can factor out the process of creating the request body:

```
def getRequestBody(String service, String serviceNamespace, Map params) {
    { ->
        "$service"(xmlns: serviceNamespace) {
            params.each { method, argument ->
                delegate."$method"(argument)
            }
         }
    }
}

def doIt(String action, String service, String serviceNamespace, Map params) {
    def client = new Client()

    client.send(action) {
        body(getRequestBody(service, serviceNamespace, params))
    }
}
```

Comment: It may be a little too late to ask, but is it possible to define such a method, `getRequestBody()`, that will return the needed `body {...}` closure? In addition to that, being able to call `getRequestBody()` in a place like: `client.send('http://...') { getRequestBody() }`? How can this be done?

Comment: Yes, but you can't call it like `client.send('http://...') { getRequestBody() }`. Instead you can code `getRequestBody` to be used like  `client.send('http://...') { body(getRequestBody()) }` or `client.send('http://...', getRequestBody())`. I added a demonstration of the first method.